# Coinbase API sending Dash Version 3 Transactions

Tags: coinbase-api

While developing an app that will be using the Coinbase API to send transactions from the user's account to the Dash Wallet app, we have found that most of these transactions are using version 3.  In Dash, Version 3 is reserved for special transactions that are related to masternode registration and quorum creation.

we are using this API (with an example):
[https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/{{from_account_id}}/transactions](https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/%7B%7Bfrom_account_id%7D%7D/transactions)

```
{
    "type": "send",
    "to": "XfVe4NAHTp6NWwuM3PGpmUSwuZuWwe9qY3",
    "amount": ".98",
    "currency": "USD",
    "idem": "9316dd16-0c05"
  }
```

Here are some transactions that were created from this API and tx version for each.

```
TX ID                                                              version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
9f787f91223f0bcba7263d3b3b0fbb4a19a073b34c84c7b231f0b067155aaa4f - 3
44dfbc084eea295d893807ba12cfb51e141b67222d6b8949a156fff274a5ae64 - 1
2cf35effb616dcd14866e0f142395b43632a5abc87628426e126fc73b472e9d9 - 3
bc667277e2e10609f3b17678934ff196aa59cbeb3cccd43a27c274e3f119fe06 - 3
e9932b23e93c06c3ec4c22be8b392d3b5e977f71ad5568afc7af16cb62ac5cce - 3
a6fc0f937eeb0e0d7a2a8f2ae97e97aaaddf5147307fe33e35aad45904b25d39 - 1
```

Is there a way to specify a tx version in the API or is this a bug on Coinbases end?  If it is a problem with Coinbase, then can the version of the transactions be changed to 1 or 2.

Comment: how are you determining the version? version isn't in the response according to the docs. https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-accounts

Comment: Dash blockchain transaction versions are determined by looking at a block explorer such as https://chainz.cryptoid.info/dash/tx.dws?9f787f91223f0bcba7263d3b3b0fbb4a19a073b34c84c7b231f0b067155aaa4f.htm

Comment: @genericHCU see the previous comment for my answer on how the version is determined.